# Insert into SQL usando um objeto JS

Tags: javascript, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-insert

Imagine que se tenha este objeto no JS:

```js
let aluno = {
    nome: "Felipe",
    idade: 70,
    notas: 10
}
```

Eu consigo escrever esses dados em uma tabela no SQL usando por exemplo o comando SQL ficando o seguinte código:

```js
let SQLText = "insert into tabela_alunos (nome, idade, nota) value (aluno.nome, aluno.idade, aluno.notas)"
let result = await pool.request().query(SQLText);
```

Entretanto, gostaria de aprender como poderia enviar e escrever na tabela do SQL no próprio formato do objeto, ou o mais próximo disso (imagine um objeto muito extenso com 20/25 propriedades, e serão vários inserts diferentes, então não seria viável para todos eles ter que fazer todo esse texto).

Queria algo que ficasse mais parecido com isso

```sql
insert into tabela_alunos values (aluno)
```

Comment: Isso não é possível no fazer direto no banco de dados, vc tem que usar algum ORM para facilitar sua vida

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o KNEX e o utilizei para solucionar o problema, ficando de forma simples e trabalhando juntamente com o 'mssql'.

```
// Adiciona o novo usuario no banco de dados
await knex('Usuarios').insert(user);
```

Onde `user` é meu objeto e eu posso tanto enviar a query diretamente para o MSSQL usando o await, ou posso retornar a string sql formada completa usando:

```
let texto = knex('Usuarios').insert(user).toString();
```